# Fetching data with Axios in React Native

Tags: react-native, web-services, axios, expo, google-places-api

I created a `react-native` app using `expo`. I am trying to query for the photos using the Google Places API but I get an `Axios` error as shown below. However, if I paste the URL on the browser it works.

This is what my code looks like:

```js
const getPlacePhoto = async (photoReference: string) => {
  const requestUrl = `
  https://places.googleapis.com/v1/${photoReference}/media?maxHeightPx=400&maxWidthPx=400&skipHttpRedirect=true&key=${EXPO_PUBLIC_GOOGLE_PLACES_API_KEY}
  `;

  try {
    const response = await axios.get(requestUrl);
    return response;
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Error fetching data:", error);
  }
};
```

Where the `requestUrl` without the key is

> https://places.googleapis.com/v1/places/ChIJW4y4WuakMRkR15X0Fx5Ayl4/photos/AWU5eFh4cUJCzd3k05Ir4ZDvp0IrMAQ7q164z6cl8qqTAKuYOT7RIFwVUrRwVlSzBpwQvtECEp93KKjtZhQSBzzujiH2ZSIw1etWLSWUewR6ozocM3cEseb9G5uo9lJ31MeW-Fck7AuZ3YUdwUVCwv9GmiROAc70j1oO6qHI/media?maxHeightPx=400&maxWidthPx=400&skipHttpRedirect=true

[image]

Comment: are you seeing this even with a basic fake api like `https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1` ? 

A full screen error like that suggests more than just a network error, it suggest the api response / page component render isn't being handled properly.

Comment: fake url like the one you wrote works. I guess maybe something up with places api. Weird thing is if i copy that url or even curl it works pretty fine...

Comment: Check that you are using all the correct headers etc

Comment: If I just past the example URL and add a valid API key, I get the correct JSON response, with the URL of the actual photo (`photoUri`). However, if the API key is not valid the HTTP response code is 400 Bad Request, and if the key is missing the HTTP response code is 403 Forbidden. Could the problem be that "network error" is reportred because the HTTP response code is not 200 OK?